# Unable to print russian characters

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, cyrillic

I have a russian string which i have encoded to UTF-8

```
String str = "\u041E\u041A";
System.out.println("String str : " + str);
```

When i print the string in eclipse console i get `??` Can anyone suggest how to print the russian strings to console or what i am doing wrong here?

I have tried converting it to bytes using `byte myArr[] = str.getBytes("UTF-8")` and then `new String(myArr, "UTF-8")` still same problem :-(

Comment: [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714)
This seems like your problem...

Comment: Go to Run > Run Configuration > Common > Change the console encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
String myString = "some cyrillic text";
byte bytes[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Or this:

```
String myString = "some cyrillic text";
byte bytes[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

The main problem with russian its to set UTF-8 encoding correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse Go to Run > Run Configuration > Common > Change the console encoding to UTF-8. You will be able to see the Russian Characters in console

Answer (score 1):

My Eclipse prints it correctly

```
String str : ОК
```

try to change Run Configurations encoding to UTF-8 or CP1251

Answer (score 0):

The display font of the console will most likely not cope with nonASCII characters.

You could try printing to a file rather then System.out

Answer (score 0):

It's an old topic, but nevertheless maybe below would help someone.

If you're reading data using `InputStream / InputStreamReader` (for example from some API) that contains Cyrillic symbols and you get some gibberish like `������ ���` or `?????? ???`, try to apply encoding Charset as second parameter of `InputStreamReader` constructor.

**EXAMPLE**:

Let's use Russian Central Bank API to get US dollars and euro price in Russian rubles. In below code we get data for the current day when we make a request. Data from API is in `xml` so we also need to parse it.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CBRFApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String output = getAndReadData("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
        Document document = loadXMLFromString(output);

        // getting root element
        Node root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList currencies = root.getChildNodes();

        // just for further reference
        Node usDollar;
        Node euro;

        for (int i = 0; i < currencies.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currency = currencies.item(i);
            String key = currency.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue();

            if (key.equals("R01235") || key.equals("R01239")) {
                if (key.equals("R01235")) // US dollar ID
                    usDollar = currency;
                else if (key.equals("R01239")) // Euro ID
                    euro = currency;

                NodeList currencySpecs = currency.getChildNodes();
                System.out.print(currencySpecs.item(1).getTextContent());
                System.out.print(" " + currencySpecs.item(3).getTextContent());
                System.out.print(" " + currencySpecs.item(4).getTextContent());
                System.out.println();
            }
      }
    }

    public static String getAndReadData(String link) {
        String output = "";
        try {

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; en-us; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/JDQ39) " +
                    "AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 Chrome/18.0.1025.308 Mobile Safari/535.19.");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            // below is the key line,
            // without second parameter - Charset.forName("CP1251") - 
            // data in Cyrillic will be returned like ������ ���
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("CP1251"));

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line;
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            return output;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml)
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            return builder.parse(inputSource);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So proper output is:

```
USD Доллар США 63,3791
EUR Евро 70,5980
```

And without indicating `Charset.forName("CP1251")`:

```
USD ������ ��� 63,3791
EUR ���� 70,5980
```

Of course actual encoding in your case may differ from `CP1251`, so if this one doesn't work, try other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in similar situation:

```java
String myString = "some cyrillic text";

byte bytes[] = myString.getBytes("windows-1251");

String value = URLEncoder.encode(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution -> right charset!

`String path = "E:\\java\\test.txt";  File file = new File(path); Scanner scan = new Scanner(file, **"CP1251"**); System.out.println(scan.nextLine());`

output was in Russian!

Answer (score -1):

In XCode you can print values by LLDB function po [SomeClass returnAnObject]
For automatic work it can be added in some action in a breakpoint. Also you need add checkbox in "Automatic continue after eval actions"

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem when I read "MyFile.txt" file with russian letters. May be helps to anyone. The solution is:

```
package j;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class J4 {
public static void Read_TXT_File(String fileName) throws 
FileNotFoundException {
try{int i=0;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "utf-8");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();

//byte bytes[] = line.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
//line = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); 
if (line.isEmpty()) {
System.out.println(i+": Empty line");
}
else {
System.out.println(i+": "+ line);
// here is your code for example String MyString = line
}
i++;
}
}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws 
FileNotFoundException {
Read_TXT_File("MyFile.txt");
}
}
```