# Java + MySQL encoding problems

Tags: java, mysql, database, odbc

Excuse me for my english.
I have a problem trying to connect to MySQL database from my Java code.
I've created database + tables. I tried to insert some values in russian, but got a lot of question marks. After that I googled a lot and found out how to change mysql charset. I added this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
character-set-filesystem = utf8
```

After restart of the app, I could add and see Russian letters in Database using terminal (terminal->'mysql'->'USE database_name;'->'SELECT * FROM table_name;') and got setting shown here:

```
show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

But when I tried to get this data from Java – I failed again. 
I've already found out that I should connect like this, but it didn't help.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Here is my Java code:

```
results = statement.executeQuery(req);
if (!results.next()) return null;
byte bytes[] = results.getBytes(1);
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
return value;
```

-----ALSO TRIED JUST LIKE THIS-----

```
results = statement.executeQuery(req);
if (!results.next()) return null;
return results.getString(1);
```

What should I do?
Thank you.

The problem was not in the MySQL part. The problem was in printing the result, but another problem is that I tried to save Emojis to the DB, but understood that utf8 is not, as good as I thought. I found out that I should convert my DB to utf8mb4 to handle Emojis, but there is a problem, because I can't proceed this string from tutorial:

```
ALTER DATABASE app-data CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-data CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

Comment: What result do you get and what is expected? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Blobonat I've inserted some Russian words using Java, can read them using terminal (without Java). Try to get them with Java and get only "????" (questions marks), but want get words.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Unable to print russian characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168868/unable-to-print-russian-characters)

Comment: @Blobonat no, still got "?????"

Comment: Can you post your java code where you print the result from the query?

Comment: @Blobonat 
results = statement.executeQuery(req);
if (!results.next())
    return null;
byte bytes[] = results.getBytes(1);
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
return value;

-----ALSO TRIED JUST LIKE THIS-----

results = statement.executeQuery(req);
if (!results.next())
    return null;
return results.getString(1);

Comment: Are you sure that your text output field can handle your russian text?

Comment: @Blobonat Oh, PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
                    out.println(result); Solved printing problem. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121059/discussion-between-nikolay-pryahin-and-blobonat).