# Problem with displaying cyrillic string with IBM Java

Tags: java, cyrillic

I'm trying to print simple cyrillic string to console using IBM Java, but instead of correct string there is trash. Latin string prints correctly.
What have i do to fix that?

I'm using IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64 Compressed References 20180425_385365 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String text = "Простой текст";
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Source string: 
"Простой текст"
Result: 
���⮩ ⥪��

Also if i'm using Oracle JDC, it works correctly.
My source code files are encoded in UTF-8, and console works in UTF-8.
Also, I've tryed to run code from [Unable to print russian characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168868/unable-to-print-russian-characters)
and get no changes.

Comment: be sure to use the same character encoding everywhere (source code, compiler settings, terminal, ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to print russian characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168868/unable-to-print-russian-characters)

Comment: Most likely your console does not support this encoding.

Comment: I've added some additional info. My console supports cyrillic encoding correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in IBM JDK: it's convert wrong cyrillic symbols in java class from cp1251 to UTF-8, so I convert  my source code to UTF-8 and rewrite text -  that's solve the problem.