# Convert Cyrillic Characters in JAVA

Tags: java, string

Can anyone help how to properly display Cyrillic Characters in the console output?

```
String repos_path = "Trade Programs/1.Тестирование";               
System.out.println(repos_path);
```

[image]

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168868/unable-to-print-russian-characters)

Comment: I did, unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: Did you try to change the run configuration?

Comment: Check also [this](https://geekflare.com/utf-8-configuration-in-websphere-weblogic-tomcat-tc-server-jboss/), Oracle Weblogic section.